# Is there a non-measurable function $f$ where $\sqrt{f}$ is measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, measurable-functions

The title is basically the question:

Does there exist a non-measurable function $f$ where $\sqrt{f}$ is measurable?

I'm honestly not sure. My book does have a proposition that if $f$ is measurable, then $f^n$ where $n \in \mathbb{N}$ are measurable. However, it states this for naturals, not rationals. While no example is given, I'd assume the reason the statement is given this way is that $f^{q}$ where $q \in \mathbb{Q}$ need not be measurable. If it was true, I think they'd state the more general statement.

I know I am asking a different question than that proposition, but being that I don't believe the proposition would be true for a $q$ power, I'm not sure what to make of the question I'm being asked. I can't seem to think of a counterexample, but I'm also not convinced it's true. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: If $g= \sqrt f$ is measurable then $f=g^2$ is measurable as well.

Comment: @MartinR Ah I see. I agree with that. Hmm, I wonder why the book states it is not true for any power of $q$ then. Very odd. Now, what about the problem at hand? If $f$ is non-measurable.

Comment: Can you add the exact quote from the book to your question? What is not true for any power $q$?

Comment: @MartinR it says, "Let $f$ be measurable. The integer powers $f^n$ where $n \geq 1$ are measurable." Since it has $n \geq 1$, that's the same thing as the naturals so I just write it like that to condense it. It only says naturals though, so I'd assume if it was a $f^q$ that it need not be true.

Comment: It *is* true, for all real positive exponents $q$.

Comment: @MartinR That is so strange that my book states it that way then. I really wonder why. It put a lot of doubt into my mind. Well, knowing that now, let's look at the problem at hand. What if $f$ is non-measurable?

Comment: The simple answer is: if $f$ is measurable, but takes negative values, then $\sqrt f$ is not well defined. (But if $f\ge 0$ everywhere, then yes, $f^q$ is measurable for all positive $q\in \Bbb Q$.)

Comment: I have posted a detailed answer to your question. Please, let me know if you have any question regarding my answer. If my answer provides relevant / helpful information regarding your question, please, upvote it. If my answer actualy answers your question, accept it too, please. To upvote, click the triangle **pointing upward above the number** (of votes) in front of the question. To accept the answer, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Part 1**: If you don't assume $f > 0$,  then $f^q$ may not uniquely defined for $q\in \Bbb Q \setminus \Bbb N$. For instance, if $f(x)=0$ and $q=-1$, $f^q(x)$ is not defined.  If $f(x)=-1$ and $q=1/2$, $f^q(x)$ can be $i$ or $-i$.

So, the real issue is what you meant by $\sqrt{f}$, when $f$ has negative values. You need to choose one branch of the complex square root and that leads to a more sophisticate environment. That is why your book (and other books) stay with $q\in \Bbb N$.

**Part 2**:"Does there exist a non-measurable function $f$ where $\sqrt{f}$ is measurable?"
As we have seen in Part 1, the real issue is to assure that  $\sqrt{f}$ is well-defined as function. If it is well-defined and it is a measurable function, then $f$ is measurable.

*Proof*: Let $g= \sqrt{f}$. Then $g$ is measurabe, So $f= g^2$ is measurable. $\square$

So, there exist **not** a non-measurable function $f$ where $\sqrt{f}$ is measurable.

Comment: That's clear! Thanks!